# Opt-out of editing other's posts

Tags: support, review-queue

How can I remove this icon from my Ask Ubuntu page?

[image: Review queues - help improve the site]

I have enough trouble trying to get my own posts formatted correctly.  When I do look at the review queue, I don't see any need for changes to a particular post and I select the option that says that no changes are needed.  Then I get a message saying that I failed and that it was a trick question.

I am not an elitist troll.  If I see something obvious in a post that I think I can improve for the person posting, I might edit it if I know how to improve the formatting on their post, but I'm not going to sit and go through a queue just looking for ways to change other people's posts.

Comment: I don't get your point to be honest, it's a voluntary task after all.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

An out of the box solution, to complement the other (better) answers: consider posting a 100 point [bounty](/help/bounty) on a question or answer that deserves it; that will bring your reputation below 500, which is the level required for [accessing the review queues](/help/privileges/access-review-queues). That will also hide the icon from the navigation bar.

Answer (score 10):

There is no in-built mechanism to remove that icon from your page.  If you don't want to participate in reviews just ignore the icon.

Answer (score 9):

"no changes needed" means that you have examined the item and have decided that it is okay in its current state.

If you select "no changes needed" without actually examining the question, then "failed" *is* an appropriate result.

There is also the "skip" option for when you don't want to suggest changes yet don't want to say it's okay.

(If you really want to get rid of the button, write your own browser extension to set style for SE pages: `.review-button-item { display: none; }` ).

Comment: I did examine the question and found that no changes were needed.  I selected the "no changes needed" option and then was told that I had not reviewed the post, but I HAD reviewed the post.  That's the source of my exasperation.

Comment: Wow, I didn't realize I could write a style sheet to deal with other people's web sites.  That's a good idea.

Comment: No need to write a browser extension if you're using Firefox or Google Chrome or Chromium (and maybe even some other browsers): install something like *Stylus* from the browser's "store", learn how to use it, and enjoy!